# Formatting an array into a sentence with null values

Tags: java, arrays, null

So I have this class Food and I wanted to output an array of fruit using another class (testFood). The issue I'm having is outputting the non-null values in proper sentence structure. I've figured out how to calculate the length of the array discounting the null values in the array (using the new method "realLength"), but still have the issue on line 54 where there is a null value in between elements but the statement does not handle it the way I'd like it. If anyone knows a way to change this, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Food{
  static final int MAX_SIZE=10;
  public static String[] favFruit=new String[MAX_SIZE]; //array of favourite fruit

  //Set member function used to set a new favourite fruit in the array of favourite fruit
  public static void addFruit(String fruit){
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
      if(favFruit[i]==null){
        favFruit[i]=fruit;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //Set member function used to set a favourite fruit in the array to null, thereby removing it
  public static void removeFruit(String fruit){
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
      if(fruit==favFruit[i]){
        favFruit[i]=null;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //Returns the length of an array minus the amount of null values
  public static int realLength(String[] arr){
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
      if(arr[i]==null){
        num++;
      }
    }
    return MAX_SIZE-num;
  }

  //Prints the list of fruit in order to prove what is in the array of favFruit
  public static void printFruit(String[] fruits){
    //Prints no fruits and returns a statement saying why
    int length=realLength(fruits);
    if(length==0){
      System.out.println("There are no favourite fruits.");
    }
    else{
      System.out.print("The favourite fruits are: ");
      for(int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++){
        //Prints the fruit without ','/'.'/'and' if and only if there is one valid fruit in the array
        if(fruits[i]!=null && length==1){
          System.out.print(fruits[i]+".");
        }
        //Prints the fruit in successive order
        else if(fruits[i]!=null && fruits[i]!=fruits[length-1]){
          System.out.print(fruits[i]+", ");
        }
        //On the last favourite fruit, this prints 'and' and '.' instead to complete the sentence
        else if(fruits[i]!=null && fruits[i]==fruits[length-1]){ //Issue: doesnt work if null is between elements
            System.out.print("and "+fruits[i]+".");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}

public class testFood{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //Add fruit to the favFruit array to test addFruit method
    Food.addFruit("Orange");
    //Print the array to prove the array has changed
    Food.printFruit(Food.favFruit);
    //Remove fruit from the favFruit array to test the removeFruit method
    Food.removeFruit("Orange");
    //Print the array to prove the array has changed
    Food.printFruit(Food.favFruit);

    //Repeat last steps to test for multiple fruit
    Food.addFruit("Banana");
    Food.addFruit("Apple");
    Food.addFruit("Pear");
    Food.addFruit("Orange");
    Food.printFruit(Food.favFruit);
    Food.removeFruit("Apple");
    Food.printFruit(Food.favFruit);
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
The favourite fruits are: Orange.
There are no favourite fruits.
The favourite fruits are: Banana, Apple, Pear, and Orange.
The favourite fruits are: Banana, and Pear.Orange,
```

Comment: not your issue, but: stop calling `realLength()` over and over. Call it once and store it's result!

Comment: This is not your issue either, but something you should change in your `removeFruit(String)` method is the testing of `if(fruit==favFruit[i])`. The only reason this is working for you at the moment is because you have declared all the Strings before you compile, and they are all the same. However, lets say you extended the program to take user-input. This method will no longer work as each input is a *new* String and are not equal. Use the `String.equals(String)` method instead. It will remove this potential issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could combat this issue. You could make a new array of the *real length* containing only the elements that are not null. Though this is not the best as you will be creating a new array every time you want to make the sentence. You could consider using a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of Strings. A list is just an array which you can add elements and remove elements from, and all the ordering is taken care of for you. So when you remove an element you are not left with null, but simply the list somewhat appears to shift over a place.

Finally, if you want to continue on how you are currently going, I wrote a simple, but effective implementation.

```
public class TestFood {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Add fruit to the favFruit array to test addFruit method
        Food.addFruit("Orange");
        //Print the array to prove the array has changed
        System.out.println(Food.makeSentence());
        //Remove fruit from the favFruit array to test the removeFruit method
        Food.removeFruit("Orange");
        //Print the array to prove the array has changed
        System.out.println(Food.makeSentence());

        //Repeat last steps to test for multiple fruit
        Food.addFruit("Banana");
        Food.addFruit("Apple");
        Food.addFruit("Pear");
        Food.addFruit("Orange");
        System.out.println(Food.makeSentence());
        Food.removeFruit("Apple");
        System.out.println(Food.makeSentence());
    }
}

public class Food {

    static final int MAX_SIZE = 10;
    public static String[] favFruit = new String[MAX_SIZE];


    /**
     * Add's a fruit, if and only if there is a space for it.
     *
     * @param fruit Name of the fruit to be added.
     */
    public static void addFruit(String fruit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            if (favFruit[i] == null) {
                favFruit[i] = fruit;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Removes the specified fruit, if it does exist in the food.
     *
     * @param fruit Name of the fruit to be removed.
     */
    public static void removeFruit(String fruit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            //Note the use of the 'equals' method
            if (fruit.equals(favFruit[i])) {
                favFruit[i] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes the used length of the array in this class.
     *
     * @return The length, or count of elements, used in this class.
     */
    public static int realLength() {
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
            if (favFruit[i] != null)
                length++;
        return length;
    }


    public static String makeSentence() {
        //Get the real length of the array
        int length = realLength();
        //Have a variable, used to tell how many more fruits are to be added.
        int fruitsToAdd = length;

        /*
        The purpose of having the two variables will be seen later. But basically
        the purpose is because of the appending of the word "and". If the real
        length of the array is 1, the fruitsToAdd variable will be 1 too. When this
        happens the word "and" will be appended even though there was only one fruit
        in the first place.
         */

        if (fruitsToAdd == 0)
            return "There are no favourite fruits.";

        //Make a StringBuilder to append everything to
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        //Append the start of the sentence to the StringBuilder, depending on how many elements there are
        if (length == 1)
            builder.append("The favourite fruit is: ");
        else
            builder.append("The favourite fruits are: ");

        //Go through all the elements in the array
        for (int position = 0; position < favFruit.length; position++) {

            //Test if the current position of the favourite fruits is not null
            if (favFruit[position] != null) {

                //If this is the last fruit to add, append it with "and [fruitName]."
                if (fruitsToAdd == 1)
                    //If the length was 1, no need to append "and"
                    if (length == 1)
                        builder.append(favFruit[position]).append(".");
                    else
                        //If there are more than 1 fruit, then append "and". Not you could easily make this one expression with a ternary statement
                        builder.append(" and ").append(favFruit[position]).append(".");
                    //Else, append the name of the fruit.
                else
                    builder.append(favFruit[position]);

                //If this is not the second last fruit (but is not the last element either), append a comma and a space for seperation.
                if (fruitsToAdd > 2)
                    builder.append(", ");

                //Decrement the amount of fruits to add.
                fruitsToAdd--;
            }
        }

        //Returns the String contents of the builder
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This gave me the output of:

```
The favourite fruit is: Orange.
There are no favourite fruits.
The favourite fruits are: Banana, Apple, Pear and Orange.
The favourite fruits are: Banana, Pear and Orange.
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot, unfortunately I was forced into having to use arrays rather than lists due to the question stating to specifically use an array.